# div inside form rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have these markup on my rails application these form is not working when i tr

```
<div class="span5 mg myform">
<div class="span5 mg">
<ul class="clearfixremo formmenu">
    <li class="lefty blocky boldy rightbrd"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Post</li>
    <li class="lefty blocky boldy myphotoupload "> <i class="icon-camera"></i> Photo</li>
</ul>
</div>
    <div class="span5 mg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
 <%= simple_form_for(current_user.posts.new, :remote => true ,:html => { :multipart =>    true } ,:class=>"form-horizontal" ) do |f| %>

 <div class="field">

<%= f.text_area :body ,:rows=>1%>

     <%= f.select :privacy,["public","friends","only me"] %>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>


<div class="span5 mg">


 <div id="pactions"  class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "#{t 'share'}",:id=>"share"%>
  </div>
 <% end %>

    </div>

   </div>
```

it shows to me on html markup that the form is closed before the select menu and when I move the submit button before the select menu and inside the field div its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the formatting and indentation of your ERB and the problem should become obvious: opening tags (including `<%= ... do %>`) must match their closing tags (including `<% end %>`). You can't:

```
<div>
    <form>
    </div>
</form>
```

you need to:

```
<div>
    <form>
    </form>
</div>
```

Your `<form>` opens one `<div>`

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user.posts.new, :remote => true ,:html => { :multipart =>    true } ,:class=>"form-horizontal" ) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
```

and then tries to close four of them:

```
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When the browser sees that invalid HTML, it will attempt to fix it by closing the `<form>` behind your back and it will pretend that you said:

```
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Once that happens, your form is broken and nothing works the way you're expecting it to.

Fix your tag nesting so that everything is closed in the opposite order that the tags are opened. And start formatting your code properly so that the structure is obvious, the computer won't care but you will.

Comment: I fixed my markup order and your answer helped me a lot thanks